# Ao criar um programa de cadastro de pedidos por que não consigo salvar as informações do primeiro item?

Tags: python, while, dicionário

Estou começando na programação e este é o meu primeiro programa. estou criando um programa que faça cadastro de pedidos de livros. Quero poder adicionar varios itens para uma mesma pessoa. Ao rodar o codigo consigo adicionar as informações solicitadas mas só consigo printar o nome e o segundo item com a sua respectiva quantidade. Desconsiderem os erros de identação, não consegui copiar do jeito correto aqui.

```
lista_de_pedidos = {}
   def cadastrar_pedido():
       nome = input("Digite o nome da pessoa: ")
       while True:
       novo_item = input("deseja cadastrar um novo item? ")
         if novo_item == "S":
        
          publicacao = input("Digite o nome da publicação: ")
          quantidade = int(input("Digite a Quantidade: "))

        else:
          break
    
       pedido = {
        "solicitante": nome,
        "item": publicacao,
        "quant_item": quantidade
       }

     lista_de_pedidos[nome] = pedido
     print("Pedido cadastrado com sucesso!")
     print(lista_de_pedidos)
     cadastrar_pedido()
```

Answer (score -3):

Opa! Somente com dicionários acredito não ser possível realizar essa tarefa, você precisa fazer um dicionário e uma lista com um dicionário dentro da sua lista para os atributos solicitante, item e quantidade, deve ficar mais ou menos assim:

```
{'joao':[{'livro':'teste','qtd':2},{'livro':'teste2','qtd':22}]}
```

Se você observar bem verá que temos um dicionário com a key joao e com o value sendo uma lista com todos os dados que você precisa.

Então para seu código funcionar da forma que quer basta:

1 - criar uma lista vazia;
2 - dar um append na lista colocando seu pedido;
3 - adicionar sua lista no dicionário.

```
   lista = []
   lista.append(pedido)
   lista_de_pedidos[nome] = lista
```

Podendo agora até excluir o solicitante já que é a key do dicionário externo e ficou redundante.

segue seu código com as modificações:

```
lista_de_pedidos = {}
lista_cliente = []
def cadastrar_pedido():
    nome = input("Digite o nome da pessoa: ")
    while True:
        novo_item = input("deseja cadastrar um novo item? ")
        if novo_item == "S":
            publicacao = input("Digite o nome da publicação: ")
            quantidade = int(input("Digite a Quantidade: "))
            
            pedido = {
                'solicitante': nome,
                'item': publicacao,
                'quant_item':quantidade
            }
            
            lista_cliente.append(pedido)
            
            
            lista_de_pedidos[nome] = lista_cliente 

        else:
            break
    
    
    print("Pedido cadastrado com sucesso!")
    print(lista_de_pedidos)

cadastrar_pedido()
```

Flws

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).